# How to use TLS 1.2 in .NET in WinXP?

Tags: c#, .net, https, windows-xp, tls1.2

I'm creating an app that is downloading some content from a HTTPS-based website (and POSTs something back). The web server is using forced encryption (TLS 1.2 with modern ciphers), so all browsers before Firefox 30 can't open pages from it. At all.

The app is written in C# using .NET 4.6 HttpWebRequest and all is working okay. But I want to add support for older Windows XP machines that are still alive, where only .NET 4.0 is available. Also it will be prefect if the app will work even in Win2000 with .NET 2.0, but it's more like a inreal dream. :)

Is it possible to add support for HTTPS requests to modern servers in .NET 2.0/4.0 app? May be via OpenSSL, Mozilla NSS or something such...

Comment: Why don't you support MS-DOS 6? ;)

Comment: Because it's not in use. But WinXP is still using by some users, and Win2k on old PCs is also still used sometimes.